# Explicit bool operator - cannot return, test, initialize bool

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, type-conversion

I just tried to use `explicit operator bool()` for the first time and its behavior is quite unexpected to me. Can someone please shed some light on why the following sections marked with `// does  not work`.

The `convertible` class would e.g. be a smart pointer class with the ability to check for the validity of the contained data.

```
struct convertible
{
  explicit operator bool() const
  {
    return ptr;
  }

  void* ptr = nullptr;
};

bool testReturn()
{
  convertible test;
  // does not work
  return test;
}

bool testReturn2()
{
  convertible test;
  // does not work
  return test == true;
}

bool testReturn3()
{
  convertible test;
  // works ?!
  return !test;
}

int main()
{
  convertible test;
  // works
  if (test) { }
  // works
  bool init(test);
  bool tested = test;
  bool tested2 = testReturn();
  bool tested3 = testReturn2();
  bool tested4 = testReturn3();
  return 0;
}
```

With GCC I get:

```
milian@minime:/tmp$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20131219 (prerelease)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

milian@minime:/tmp$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp: In function ‘bool testReturn()’:
test.cpp:15:10: error: cannot convert ‘convertible’ to ‘bool’ in return
  return test;
          ^
test.cpp: In function ‘bool testReturn2()’:
test.cpp:22:15: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘convertible’ and ‘bool’)
  return test == true;
              ^
test.cpp:22:15: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:22:15: note: operator==(int, int) <built-in>
test.cpp:22:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘convertible’ to ‘int’
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:39:17: error: cannot convert ‘convertible’ to ‘bool’ in initialization
  bool tested = test;
```

With Clang it's similar:

```
milian@minime:/tmp$ clang++ --version
clang version 3.4 (tags/RELEASE_34/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
milian@minime:/tmp$ clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp 
test.cpp:15:10: error: no viable conversion from 'convertible' to 'bool'
  return test;
        ^~~~
test.cpp:22:15: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('convertible' and 'int')
  return test == true;
        ~~~~ ^  ~~~~
test.cpp:39:8: error: no viable conversion from 'convertible' to 'bool'
  bool tested = test;
      ^        ~~~~
3 errors generated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to disable certain conversions, just disable them through the `delete` specifier:

```
struct convertible
{
    operator bool() const //(Implicit) Conversion to bool allowed
    {
        return true;
    }

    operator int() const = delete; //Implicit/Explicit conversions to int disallowed 
                                   //(Results in compilation error).
};


int main()
{
    convertible c;

    if( c )
        ...

    int a = c; //ERROR
    int b = (int)c; //ERROR (The same for static_cast<int>(c) )
}
```

You could also delete all types except which are explicitly overloaded using a templated version of the conversion operator:

```
struct foo
{
    operator bool() const //Explicit overload for bool
    {
       return true; 
    }

  template<typename T>
  operator T() const = delete; //Everithing which is not a bool (Everithing which  
                               //does not fit in the explicit overload) would  
                               //resolve to this operator and will fail.
};


int main()
{
    foo f;

    bool b = f; //OK
    int i = f;  //ERROR
    char c = f; //ERROR
    etc...
}
```

Comment: Awesome - that's just what I want! What's odd though is that this still doesn't work as expected: `foo f; f == true;` It apparently tries to convert with an int here?

Comment: @milianw First: Don't write conitionals like `if( f == true )`. Just write `if( f )`. `== true` is redundant. BTW  `true` and `false` keywords are defined as integers? LOL. Just don't write `== true`

Comment: @milianw [I have posted a question about the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351450/implicit-conversion-to-boolean-and-comparison-with-boolean-literals). Seems like boolean comparisons are promoted to integral comparisons, so in the case of a user defined conversion vs bool comparison the integer conversion is requested.

Answer (score 0):

If your cast operator is `explicit`, you need to cast it, something like:

```
return static_cast<bool>(test);
```

Comment: Yes, I know it's explicit. I want to disallow conversions to anything but bool - i.e. the implicit upcasting of bool to int is what I'd expect to see forbidden. Yet a conversion to bool should be just fine, no? Put differently: What's the difference between `bool a = convertible;` and `if (convertible)` - both should convert to bool just fine, no?

Comment: A bit simpler than `static_cast` could be `bool(test)`. @milianw: The standard explicitly states that when used as a condition it will use an *explicit* conversion operator. The aim is to support `explicit operator bool() const` in things like `istream`, rather than resorting to the good old *safe bool idiom*.