# Implicit conversion to boolean and comparison with boolean literals

Tags: c++, c++11

I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350924/explicit-bool-operator-cannot-return-test-initialize-bool/), about the topic of user defined conversions to `bool` and how to disable other conversions:

```
struct foo
{
    operator bool() const //Explicit overload for bool
    {
       return true; 
    }

  template<typename T>
  operator T() const = delete; //Everithing which is not a bool (Everithing which  
                               //does not fit in the explicit overload) would  
                               //resolve to this operator and will fail.
};


int main()
{
    foo f;

    bool b = f; //OK
    int i = f;  //ERROR
    char c = f; //ERROR
    etc...
}
```

Later the OP asked me why conditionals like `if( f == true )` failed (Where `f` is a `foo`. I have tried that by myself and that surprises me because that comparison with boolean literals leads to a conversion to `int` (Which is disabled) instead of `bool`:

```
int main()
{
    foo f;

    if( f ); //OK, converts to bool
    if( f == true ); //ERROR: Conversion to int, which has been disabled
}
```

> prog.cpp:20:12: error: use of deleted function ‘foo::operator T()
>   const [with T = int]’    if( f == true);
>   ..............................................................................................................................................^

My question is: **Are boolean literals defined as integers (Like the common C macros `#define true 1 #define false 0`), and if not, why that comparison lead to an int conversion instead of a `bool`?**

I'm using GCC4.8.1 with C++11 enabled ( `-std=C++11` ).

[Here](http://ideone.com/8Ch5Jg) is an example of that behavior at ideone.

Comment: Note there's an interesting difference in a related example between [g++4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2865b8fea3021b4) and [clang++3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc3c7a74ee58d588)

Comment: It might be a defect in the Standard, see [CWG 954](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#954) (open issue), especially the comment *"Some implementations unambiguously choose the `int` candidate. Perhaps the overload resolution rules could be tweaked to prefer candidates in which L and R are the same type?"* (which is the missing piece in my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `foo` is a class type, special rules apply when using an operator that is not specifically defined for that class type, see [over.built]/12

> For every pair of promoted arithmetic types `L` and `R`, there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> LR operator*(L, R);
> LR operator/(L, R);
> LR operator+(L, R);
> LR operator-(L, R);
> bool operator<(L, R);
> bool operator>(L, R);
> bool operator<=(L, R);
> bool operator>=(L, R);
> bool operator==(L, R);
> bool operator!=(L, R);
> ```
>
> where `LR` is the result of the usual arithmetic conversions between types `L` and `R`.

Not the usage of the term *promoted arithmetic types*: This requires a promotion of `bool`.

A `bool` is promoted to an `int`, see [conv.prom]/6 (integral promotions)

> A prvalue of type bool can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

---

So there are candidate functions of the form

```
common_type<L,int> operator==(L, int);
```

where `L` is a promoted arithmetic type. However, there are many of them, for example

```
common_type<int      , int> operator==(int      , int);
common_type<long     , int> operator==(long     , int);
common_type<long long, int> operator==(long long, int);
```

Each of which require a user-defined conversion from `foo` to the promoted type. It is not clear to me why this isn't ambiguous, as `foo` can be converted to any of them. This is also described in the open issue [CWG 954](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#954).

If there are several non-template conversion functions, [g++4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ad9c0e69672e0e2) and [clang++3.5](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee9c8cc61740f67b) report this ambiguity. (It should be noted that clang might have a bug here, see [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a336b5d38575b49e) which works fine with g++4.8.1.)

---

However, there is no candidate of the form

```
common_type<bool, int> operator==(bool, int);
```

as `bool` is *not* a promoted arithmetic type. Therefore, the conversion from `foo` to `bool` will *not* be chosen for the expression

```
foo x;
x == true
```

Comment: The answer is not complete, I think. There's still a piece missing.

Comment: I have noted that. I'm waiting :)

Comment: @Manu343726 The piece missing is some statement that says that the class type truly needs to be converted to the same type as the promoted `bool`. It might be a bit subtle, e.g. the built-in `operator==` requiring the same types on the left and right hand side.

Comment: @dyp another question that arises is whether a `bool operator==(bool,bool)` exsists or whether `true==true` will result in a call to `bool operator==(int,int)`.

Comment: @Paranaix `true == true` uses a built-in operator, not a function. The operands of built-in `==` will be promoted before comparison, see [expr.eq]/1 referring to [expr.rel]/2 referring to [expr]/10 referring to [conv.prom](/6)

Comment: @Manu343726 Added the missing piece. Still not complete, but I doubt I'll find out more about it soon.

Comment: That clarifies the behavior. What I don't understand is why the booleans are converted to ints to do the comparison. OK, they are really ints, but does not this behavior breaks the consistency strict rules of the type system? I mean, C++ type system is strict in general, no magic conversions are allowed by default, and each type is treated in its own scope of operations. Conversions from one type to other are performed only when different "operation scopes" overlap.

Comment: So `int` operations work with `int`s, almost for the basic operations (Arithmetic operatiosn, comparisons, etc). Why is not the same for `bool`? All comparison operations on basic types promotes to integer comparison because is what the hardware does?

Comment: @Manu343726 These rules are inherited from C; indeed AFAIK they try to replicate the behaviour of the hardware. Integral promotions aren't restricted to `bool`s, but also apply to `char`s and `short`s etc. For example, `short s = 1, t = 2; auto x = s+t;` declares `x` as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Type bool is *not* #defined in C++.  I'm thinking that the comparison promotes to int and requires the int conversion.

Comment: Thats what I think, I know that bool literals are not `#define`d. Is just that behavior surprises me. Anybody has references to the Standard saying that?

Comment: The bool is converted to int for the comparison.  I don't have a ref to the standard (need to download that, huh…) but I'm pretty sure that the bool => int combined with the lack of an int conversion on the class foo is the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do a quick test here:

```
template <typename T>
struct OutputType;

int main()
{
    OutputType<decltype(true)> a;
}
```

Atleast ideone outputs here that `true` is of type `bool`: http://ideone.com/Gm653T

However:

> The type bool can be converted to int with the value false becoming ​0​ and true becoming 1.

Source: [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion)

And my guess is that exactly such a promotion happens here